# Recommended TeamCity set-up for multiple projects

Tags: php, .net, unit-testing, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've been asked to begin setting up a Continuous Integration environment for some of the (.NET and PHP) projects we are working on within my company. Since I'm not that experienced yet this entails some digging around concerning best practices in setting up these kinds of environments.

One of the main questions I haven't been able to solve so far is whether or not it is recommended to use one central TeamCity server for all the different (and independent) projects, or is it preferable to separate them further by having a TeamCity installation for each individual project?

I'm very interested in the advantages and disadvantages in both approaches, so if anyone could  offer their input I would be very grateful.

Comment: Not used TC, but I can't see any advantage in having multiple installations - that sounds like it will result in more maintenance work. Go with the simplest approach first, and then tweak from there if your workflow turns out to require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely little advantages of having multiple TeamCity installations. Separate installations would require separate servers (or at least ports) and separate licenses (if not using the free edition).

TeamCity has support for a hierarchy of projects (basically a container for build configurations) so you can create as many projects as you need in the same installation, with each project having a set of build configurations. TeamCity also support multiple build agents so you can have builds running concurrently on different machines, whether they are Windows or Linux based.

Unless you've got some special security requirements that TeamCity's access control permissions can't fulfil, or your are running hundreds of projects and agents and the performance is poor I don't see any reason to start with more than one installation.

If the need arises in the future, you can always migrate projects to another installation without too much pain.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the following advantages to separate the instances:

- you can save license costs by using the free edition for all or some of the projects
- scaling is easier, e.g. the storage space for the artifacts ("divide and conquer")
- downtimes are easier to manage: the more teams and projects on one instance, the more difficult it becomes to find a time window for downtimes (updates, changes, plugin installation...)
- each instance can have a different configuration, for instance different plugins or versions thereof
- isolation of the data between the projects (security)
- configuration is much easier if you anyway need to isolate the projects from each other (access rights, roles, usable agents...)
- instance admin rights can be given to different people or groups

On the downside:

- updates and plugin installations have to be repeated
- potentially many possible TeamCity configurations
- data cannot be easily shared between instances

Trying to summarize: if the projects share a lot (artifacts, source code, roles, admins, release cycle...), put them on one instance. If they don't, then you can consider to put them on separate instances to get the advantages mentioned above, but you have to be ready to pay the price, especially in terms of administration.